# Dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 / Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm not understanding about the disk partitioning with Windows 10 for a dual boot. I'm just able to boot with legacy devices (Ubuntu), but when I try to boot in efi mode, then the default boot device is missing.
I've created a bootable USB stick:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso  of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress
```

I was following an installation tutorial, and now I have the following disk partitions:

```
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 210282495 209715200   100G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 210282496 210286591      4096     2M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p6 210286592 218675199   8388608     4G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p7 218675200 498069503 279394304 133,2G Linux filesystem
```

Does someone have a suggestion how grub can handle this partition or how I should reinstall Ubuntu?

I booted linux in efi mode without security boot, reinstalled linux beside windows

```
Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296 197165314 196598019  93.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 197167104 498069503 300902400 143.5G Linux filesystem
```

Now I getting a message in blue blue box from bios:

**DEFAULT BOOT DEVICE MISSING OR BOOT FAILED. INSERT RECOVERY MEDIA AND HIT ANY KEY.**

Something is missing.

Comment: You have Windows installed in UEFI mode. Please boot and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode as well. Doing otherwise will give you a lot a problems and not a dual boot.

Comment: Start by removing all the partitions related to Ubuntu - the main partition, swap and the "BIOS boot" - then disable Legacy in UEFI to assure you're booting in the correct mode. If you have Nvidia you may need `nomodeset`.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Boot-Repair's advanced mode if you boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode will let you uninstall grub-pc and install grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot. You may need to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI settings. lWhat brand/model system? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Is UEFI able to boot this usb stick created with dd? @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: The Ubuntu ISO boots in any mode.